# Different behaviour of the required field validator in Edge and chrome?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

[image][No red color is coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3YfM.png)

[image: red box is coming outside the text box.]

How to make it consistent ? either both should have color or none.

```html
<form action="">
    <input id="email" type="email" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: impossible to figure out without your code. Edit your question and hit ctrl + M and put your code in

Comment: Added the code.Just want the consistent CSS in both the browser on submit button hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Edge gives the input an `outline` property if validation fails. You can reset it like this:

```css
#email2 {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    Email: <input id="email" type="email" required="required" />
    Confirm Email: <input id="email2" type="email" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. with this header on the top of my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta charset="utf-8"  />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```